# Is it possible to quit iOS app after we do some checks

Tags: iphone, ios, launch, quit

We don't want the user enter our app if the app is out-dated.

Is that is possible to quit a iOS app when we do some date check BEFORE the app launch?

Or it is possible to quit the application after the main view is loaded?

Comment: you can use abort(); function

Comment: I never used it, but I think this should work `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil]`

Comment: You can, but if this is an app store app, it will be rejected.

Comment: anyone knows how the famous app "waze" was accepted in iStore even if it includes a "quit" button that close the app by code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before the app launches: no. The launch animation is already in progress when the OS calls `main`.

After some time (1-2 sec): yes. You can use one of

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];
exit(0);
abort();
assert(0);
pthread_kill(pthread_self());
```

so many ways, but neither will go through AppStpre - you're not supposed to close your app programmatically. You're supposed to notify the user via an UIAlertView about the outdated app and disable interaction with the app.

Comment: Very correct H2CO3. Just want to add that if we use exit(1) and delay the exit time, it may pass through appStore.

Comment: @Nitish Nice, didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple you cannot exit(quit) your application through code. i.e if you use exit(0). Your application will be rejected for that. Although you can use exit(1) and delay the exit time of your application. Or you may like to use local notification which is quite handy.

> ## Don’t Quit Programmatically
>
> ---
>
> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to
>   interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent
>   your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your
>   users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.
>   Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two
>   choices.
>
> **Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a
>   correction.** A screen provides feedback that reassures users that
>   there’s nothing wrong with your application. It puts users in control,
>   letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and
>   continue using your application or press the Home button and open a
>   different application
>
> **If only some of your application's features are not working, display
>   either a screen or an alert when people activate the feature.** Display
>   the alert only when people try to access the feature that isn’t
>   functioning.

<sup>[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)</sup>

Comment: you sure about the delay and exit(1) method can really go through the App Store?

Comment: This is like trying to trick the review process. You should NOT do that. Never exit the app yourself, no matter what the reason is!

Comment: anyone knows how the famous app "waze" was accepted in iStore even if it includes a "quit" button that close the app by code?