# Will providing a user-selectable option to quit an iOS app result in its rejection by Apple

Tags: ios, exit

I am working on an app that I feel would enhance the user experience if it provided an option for users to quit the app. This option would only be available from one of its screens.

I have researched this idea and I am fully aware of the following:

- [Technical Q&A QA1561](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html)
- [Quit iOS Application Programmatically with UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391706/quit-ios-application-programmatically-with-uialertview)
- [Is it possible to quit iOS app after we do some checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242319/is-it-possible-to-quit-ios-app-after-we-do-some-checks)

However, what I am proposing is a situation where one of the screens provides users with a range of options via a number of buttons. Each button has an icon and is clearly labelled.

Since the *Quit App* option would allow users to manually quit the app, the user will not then think the app has crashed. And, because the function of the button is to quit the app, then this isn't a case where the app was unable to provide its intended function. In fact, it's the exact opposite as the intended function is to quit the app.

**My question is**:

**If this is a user-selectable option that is clearly labelled in terms of what it does, will Apple still reject it? If so, would it make any difference if the app provided a 'confirmation alert' after the user selects the option?**

I am hoping that someone can either:

- share their experience of having tried the same approach
- refer me to an existing app that does this (as an example that it would be approved)

Comment: Every app comes with a "quit the app" button. It's the physical button below the screen. Why provide the user an in-app option to exit the app when all they have to do is press the Home button?

Comment: I am talking about 'Quitting' the app, not merely navigating away from the app to another. Because of the nature of this particular app, there would be a benefit in terms of the user experience in offering this option from within this particular screen.

Comment: If they reject it, you just fix the issue and resubmit.  It isn't really a big deal if you have to tweak something before they accept it.

Comment: @Monomeeth what did you end up doing? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

Actually about this Apple provide detailed answer in this [link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html)

Kindly follow it.

Basic Snapshot :

> In iOS, the user presses the Home button to close applications. Should
>   your application have conditions in which it cannot provide its
>   intended function, the recommended approach is to display an alert for
>   the user that indicates the nature of the problem and possible actions
>   the user could take — turning on WiFi, enabling Location Services,
>   etc. Allow the user to terminate the application at their own
>   discretion.

Apple is says gave the Warning to developer to do not call exit methods forcefully.

> **Warning: Do not call the exit function. Applications calling exit will**
>   **appear to the user to have crashed, rather than performing a graceful**
>   **termination and animating back to the Home screen.**

If during development or testing it is necessary to terminate your application, the abort function, or assert macro is recommended.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but I was already aware of this. In my case the app is still perfectly capable of providing its intended function, and my proposal means the app will not appear to the user as if it has crashed.

Comment: If your application is crash while running the user will notice it always. If the application is in background mode then it can be crash/restart even after change of some permission changes in setting.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you meant by _If the application is in background mode then it can be crash/restart even after change of some permission changes in setting_?

Comment: Yes sure, For example if in your app you are getting picture from device then first time it will ask for the permission if you don't allow and then you just change the permission from the setting at that time if your application is in stack then it will restart again with permission preference.